# Should I use the commands My Sql in capital letters?

Tags: mysql

Please excuse me if my question is simple. because when I see the examples about `php` and `MySql` in internet, they use from the capital letters for commends `MySql`.

Is it necessary to use the capital letters in `MySql`?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

Comment: No, It is only convention in SQL

Comment: No. The reserved words in MySQL are case insensitive. Writing them in upper case, just helps the readability of the query.

Comment: The choice of case is definitely a matter of opinion, and hence not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not required to use capital letters. You could use small letters too.

However for structure of code, to beautify the code and to show highlights it is better to use Capital letters in syntax such as INSERT instead of insert. This will help to identify easily when we write complicated scripts with subqueries.

And as per human nature, Capital letters are fast visible than small letters.

Hope this helps.